# Maven execute jar in remote server

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm using maven to deploy my spring boot application. Once i deploy the jar to the remote server I want to execute the jar in the remote machine and demonise the execution. Is there a possibility with Maven

Comment: start looking at plugin sshexec  :http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/sshexec-mojo.html

Comment: Thank you J. It worked fine. Still once the execution started in the remote server I want to return to the build i.e) There is no return provided in Jar and I need the the jar to be executed in background or as a daemon process